# Cronjob executes a .sh with error

Tags: java, shell, cron

I have a .sh script that works perfectlly when I execute it manually.
If I try to run it with a cronjob, I get

```
nohup: failed to run command `java': No such file or directory
```

.sh file:

```
nohup java -Xmx2048m -jar magicBox.jar $* -d appNameiResource -re > /nfs/inf/storage/logs/magicBox/magicBox_refresh.log 2>&1 &
```

cronjob:

```
#M      H       D       M       W       Command
 15     10      *       *       5       cd /home/user1/magicBox; ./startup_refresh.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.. I replaced the "java" part with the apsolute java path on the server, which I got from this command

```
which java
```

this is my .sh script now:

```
nohup /home/user/bin/jre1.7.0_101/bin/java -Xmx2048m -jar magicbox.jar $* -d basysiResource -re > /nfs/inf/storage/logs/magicBox/magicBox_refresh.log 2>&1 &
```